# Table becomes Fixed on scroll down

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

This is the page example I am working on :  http://tommywebdesigner.com/Vision.html

I want the part from the Title *Vision General* till the *icon arrow down* gets fixed on the top when I scroll down the page. Can you tell me the best method to achieve that?

Basically I have seen an [example](http://oberoncinematografica.com/cine_post/dictado_cine/?lang=es) where the class becomes fixed when the page comes to the div. My case should be similar but without the menu fixed as in this [example](http://oberoncinematografica.com/cine_post/dictado_cine/?lang=es).

Comment: This will have to be done using Javascript and the CSS property `position:fixed;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From taking a look at the other examples I've located the javascript that takes care of that for you. They use jQuery. Here is the code, Sorry it's long:

```
/*
 *
 * Fold/unfold header
 *
*/
var snapped = false;
function fixHeader(){
    $('#headercontainer, body').addClass('fixed')
}


function headerUnfold(){
    $("header").animate({
        "height" : 157
    },300, "swing");


    //if header is fixed
    if($('body.fixed').length && !snapped){
        $('#content').animate({
            'margin-top' : 185
        },300, "swing");
    }
    if($('body.fixed').length && snapped){
        $('#submenucontainer').animate({
            'margin-top' : 90
        },300, "swing");
    }


    $("nav, #menu_aux").fadeIn('fast');
    $("#menuback").hide();
    $("header").bind('mouseleave' , function(){
        headerFold(true);
    })
    }

    function headerFold(animate){
    $("header").unbind('mouseleave');
    if(animate){
        time = 300;
    }else{
        time = 0;
    }
    $("header").animate({
        "height" : 65
    },time, "swing")

    //if header is fixed
    if($('body.fixed').length && !snapped){
        $('#content').animate({
            'margin-top' : 80
        },300, "swing");
    }

    if($('body.fixed').length && snapped){
        $('#submenucontainer').animate({
            'margin-top' : 0
        },300, "swing");
    }


    if(animate){
        $("nav, #menu_aux").fadeOut('fast');
    }else{
        $("nav, #menu_aux").hide();
    }

    $("#menuback").css({
        "left" : -10
    }).show().animate({
        "left" : 20
    },time)
    }

    $("#menuback").bind('mouseenter', function(){
    headerUnfold();
    })
```

Just make the element that you want the effect for id `submenucontainer`. If you want a more direct link to the JS [here it is](http://oberoncinematografica.com/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/js/script-starter.js?ver=3.3.1).

Comment: i have followed this example : http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/ and it worked for me.

Comment: The request has changed , i made an other question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109677/create-a-table-position-fixed-inside-a-div-collapse