# Create a table position fixed inside a div collapse

Tags: css, css-position, jquery-scrollable

I have a special request, click [here](http://tommywebdesigner.com/Vision.html). to look the case.

Once I click over the arrow down and the div collapses, I need to make fixed the first table in the div collapsing and making scroll the other table below.

I hope the explanation is clear. How would you achieve that?